# SwiftUI problem with not reloading Tab Item when using NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I'm using Navigation View inside TabView and the problem is that if I an on Tab A and with NavigationView I open other Views,  when changing from tab A to B and after a while I came back to tab A I dosen't reload tab A from beginning but it show the last View open with NavitagionLink. The problem is that in each View I'm getting data from a DB and because of that if shows an empty view.

My ContentView looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var appState = AppState()
    
    @State var currentTab : Tab
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView(selection: $appState.currentTab) {
            
            NavigationView {
                HomeView(appState: appState)
                
            }
            .tabItem {
                if appState.currentTab == .home {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                }
                
                Text(LocalizedStringKey("HomeTabMenu"))
                
            }.tag(Tab.home)
            
            NavigationView {
                SearchView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                if appState.currentTab == .search {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill")
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                }
                Text(LocalizedStringKey("SearchTabMenu"))
            }.tag(Tab.search)
            
            NavigationView {
                AddItemView(appState: appState)
            }
            .tabItem {
                if appState.currentTab == .add {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                }
                Text(LocalizedStringKey("SellTabMenu"))
            }.tag(Tab.add)
            
            NavigationView {
                ShoppingCartFavoritesView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                if appState.currentTab == .favorites {
                    Image(systemName: "cart.fill")
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "cart")
                }
                Text(LocalizedStringKey("CartTabMenu"))
            }.tag(Tab.favorites)
            
            NavigationView {
                ProfileView(appState: appState)
            }
            .tabItem {
                if appState.currentTab == .profile {
                    Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                }
                Text(LocalizedStringKey("ProfileTabMenu"))
            }.tag(Tab.profile)
            
        }//End TabView
        .accentColor(Color("ColorMainDark"))
        
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(currentTab: Tab.home)
    }
}

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentTab : Tab = .home
}

enum Tab {
    case home, search, add, favorites, profile
}
```

And if I open `SearchView()`

```
struct SearchView: View {
   var body: some View {
       NavigationLink(destination: View_2(id: "ABC")){
          Text("ABC")
       }
  }
}
```

```
struct View_2: View {

   @ObservedObject var performSearchProducts = PerformSearchInProducts() 
   var id  : String

   var body: some View {
      ScollView {
         ForEach(performSearchProducts.products) { product in
            Text(product.name)
         }
      }.onAppear(perform: {
         self.performSearchProducts.searchSubCategory(id: id)
      })
  }
}
```

If in `SearchView` I'm on `View_2()` and the I open another Tab, when I come back to tab `SearchView` it doesn't show the `SearchView()`, but it remains on `View_2()` with the back button in navigation bar.

How can I make to show `SearchView()` and not keep the state of NavigationLink?

Answer (score 1):

It's the default behavior. Attach id to TabView.

```
}//End TabView
      .accentColor(Color("ColorMainDark"))
        .id(appState.currentTab) //<--Here
```

Comment: When I do this , when I go back on SearchView it reload how I wanted, but if I press on another tab, app crash. Here is a link with the error screenshot: https://ibb.co/bRy99jN